# What kind of information should I search to organize and store my text based hierarchical data?

Tags: search, data-mining

I have tried searching information like 'data mining' 'data tool', but I'm unable to find what I'm looking for.

I have these data, that I want to arrange and search. Lets say Books as main data. (Another as main would be Equipment).
Then there's history, music, sports as sub-data
then there's 3rd level data, for music it would be - Pop, Rock, Hip-hop etc.

So, I created a webpage, added word 'Book' and added links(as tool-tip) Music and Rock.
So when I move cursor over such links, it can give me more info about it.

But doing it with webpage is tedious work. And Searching won't be possible without programming. Its just example and I don't want web or online related tool. Something offline that has good storing and searching capability.

So can anybody point me to the right direction ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to assign certain characteristics to an object, probably using a template. So If a write a sparrow, I can call bunch of templates like bird, nest, fly. Similar like wiki or programming language. But in wiki you need to click on link, whereas I want immediate information as a pop-up or in a side window.

Comment: Nevermind, you can close it.